# Forwarding a variadic function parameters onto another variadic function

Tags: c++

A function calls [`sd_bus_call_method`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sd_bus_call_methodv.3.html) which accepts `...` as part of it's parameters. This function kicks up a authentication box when running unit tests so I have created an override-able  `call_sd_bus_call_method` that only calls the underlying `sd_bus_call_method`.  However how do I pass on the variadic parameters?

```
int Class::call_sd_bus_call_method(sd_bus *bus, const char *destination,
                              const char *path, const char *interface,
                              const char *member, sd_bus_error *ret_error,
                              sd_bus_message **reply, const char *types,
                              ...) {
    return sd_bus_call_method(bus, destination, path, interface, member, ret_error, reply, types, ...); // this causes an error: `expected primary-expression before '...' token.
}
```

Comment: Looks like `sd_bus_call_methodv` is made for this.

Comment: Thanks.  I searched but only got one that they rewrite using variadic templates.

Comment: @Mat I just get a sd_bus_methodv was not declared in this scope.  When was this function introduced?  I am running on Debian 9.3.  EDIT:  Appears it hasn't been released yet.